# How to refresh the activity's data when we return from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Here, I want to make an app which is having `profile activity` and user can see his/her information in that and the `activity` has one button for editing the profile. When button is clicked the new activity is opened where user can edit there information & press save button and then return to profile activity. 
So my question is how can I reload the profile activity with edited information?

here is my Edit profile activity

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

Button save_profile;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
EditText user_name,user_email,user_phone,user_addhar_number,birthdate;
ImageView user_profile_bg,user_profile,back_arrow;

private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE=24;

//db_details
String db_email="",db_name="",db_birthday,db_phone=" ";
String db_profile_pic = "",db_profile_pic_bg = "",db_token="";

String email,phone,name,profile_pic_url=" ",gender=" ",birthday;
String token="",addhar_number,new_profile_pic_url;

private double currentLatitude;
private double currentLongitude;

private boolean check_flag = false;

byte[] profile_pic_array;
byte[] profile_pic_bg_array;
Bitmap bitmap_profile= null,bitmap_bg=null;

Calendar mycalender;
ImageView CurrentImageView = null;
int choosebutton;
private long imei_number = 0;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Bitmap selectedImage = null;
Bitmap selectedImage2 = null;

SQliteHandler db;

private static final String TAG = EditProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    user_name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user_name);
    user_email =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user_email);
    user_phone =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user_phone);
    user_addhar_number =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user_aadhar_number);
    birthdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_user_birthday);

    user_profile_bg =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header_cover_image);
    user_profile=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_photo);
    back_arrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_back);

    mycalender = Calendar.getInstance();

    save_profile =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_profile_save);

    db=new SQliteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);




    back_arrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    save_profile.setOnClickListener(this);

    user_profile_bg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check_flag =true;
           CurrentImageView = (ImageView) v;
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            choosebutton=1;
        }
    });

    user_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check_flag =true;
           CurrentImageView = (ImageView) v;
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            choosebutton=2;
        }
    });

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mycalender.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mycalender.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mycalender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }
    };
        if(db_birthday != null && db_birthday != " " ){
            birthdate.setText(db_birthday);
            birthdate.setClickable(false);
        }else {
            birthdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(EditProfileActivity.this, date, mycalender.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            mycalender.get(Calendar.MONTH), mycalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                    }
            });
        }


    Intent data = getIntent();
    if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")) {
        name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        email = data.getStringExtra("email");
        profile_pic_url = data.getStringExtra("profile_url");
        token = data.getStringExtra("token");
        currentLatitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);
        currentLongitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.0);
    }else if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")){
        name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");
        profile_pic_url = data.getStringExtra("profile_url");
        token = data.getStringExtra("token");
        currentLatitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);
        currentLongitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.0);
    }


    //load user data from sqlite
    if(email != null && email !=" ") {
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getuserdetails(email);
        db_name = user.get("name");
        db_email = user.get("email");
        db_phone = user.get("phone");
        db_profile_pic = user.get("profile_pic");
        db_profile_pic_bg = user.get("profile_pic_bg");
        birthday = user.get("birthday");
        db_token= user.get("token");
    }else if(phone != null && phone !=" "){
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getuserdetails(phone);
        db_name = user.get("name");
        db_email = user.get("email");
        db_phone = user.get("phone");
        db_profile_pic = user.get("profile_pic");
        db_profile_pic_bg = user.get("profile_pic_bg");
        birthday = user.get("birthday");
        db_token= user.get("token");
    }

    user_name.setText(name);
    if ((email != " " && email != null)&&(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())){
        user_email.setText(email);
        KeyListener keyListener = user_email.getKeyListener();
        user_email.setKeyListener(null);
    }else if((phone !=" " && phone !=null)&& (Pattern.compile("^[789]\\d{9}$").matcher(phone).matches())) {
        user_phone.setText("+91 " + phone);
        KeyListener keyListener = user_phone.getKeyListener();
        user_phone.setKeyListener(null);
    }

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(profile_pic_url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avtar)
            .centerCrop()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
            .into(user_profile);

    radioGroup =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gender_rg);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int i) {
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(i);
            switch (i){
                case R.id.rb_male:
                    gender = "male";
                    break;

                case R.id.rb_female:
                    gender = "female";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_profile_save:
            name = user_name.getText().toString();
            email = user_email.getText().toString();
            phone = user_phone.getText().toString();
            addhar_number = user_addhar_number.getText().toString();
            birthday = birthdate.getText().toString();

            if(!check_flag) {
                if (profile_pic_url != null && !profile_pic_url.equals(" ") && !profile_pic_url.isEmpty()) {
                    BitMap m = new BitMap();
                    try {
                        bitmap_profile = m.execute(profile_pic_url).get();
                        bitmap_bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.beach);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    profile_pic_array = bitmapToByte(bitmap_profile);
                    profile_pic_bg_array = bitmapToByte(bitmap_bg);

                } else {
                    bitmap_profile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.default_avtar);
                    bitmap_bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.beach);
                    profile_pic_array = bitmapToByte(bitmap_profile);
                    profile_pic_bg_array = bitmapToByte(bitmap_bg);
                }
            }else{
                profile_pic_array = bitmapToByte(selectedImage2);
                profile_pic_bg_array = bitmapToByte(selectedImage);
            }
            String profile_pic= null;
            String profile_pic_bg = null;
            profile_pic = Base64.encodeToString(profile_pic_array,Base64.DEFAULT);
            profile_pic_bg = Base64.encodeToString(profile_pic_bg_array,Base64.DEFAULT);

            db.updateUser(name,email,phone,addhar_number,gender,profile_pic,profile_pic_bg,birthday,token);
            updateProfile();

            break;

        case R.id.iv_back:
            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(home);
            break;
    }
}

private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.UK);

    birthdate.setText(sdf.format(mycalender.getTime()));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selected_image = data.getData();
        new_profile_pic_url = selected_image.toString();
        Log.d("new profile_pic_url",new_profile_pic_url);
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selected_image,filePath,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            if(choosebutton==1) {
                selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(selected_image)
                        .crossFade()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(CurrentImageView);

            }else if(choosebutton ==2){
                selectedImage2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(selected_image)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
                        .into(CurrentImageView);

            }
            cursor.close();
    }
}
public byte[] bitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,baos);

    return baos.toByteArray();
} private class BitMap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}

        private void showDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

And my profile activity class is here

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView heder_bg,profile_pic,back;
Button edit_profile;
TextView tv_name,tv_email,tv_phone,tv_birthday;

String email=" ",phone=" ",name,profile_pic_url,token;

//db_details
String db_email="",db_name="",birthday = " ",db_phone=" ";
String db_profile_pic = "",db_profile_pic_bg = "";

private double currentLatitude;
private double currentLongitude;

//datetbase variables
SQliteHandler db;

private static final String TAG = ProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    heder_bg =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_header_cover_image);
    profile_pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_user_profile_photo);
    back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_back);

    edit_profile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_profile);

    tv_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    tv_email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
    tv_phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_phone);
    tv_birthday = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_birthday);

    Intent data = getIntent();
    if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")) {
        name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        email = data.getStringExtra("email");
        profile_pic_url = data.getStringExtra("profile_url");
        token = data.getStringExtra("token");
        currentLatitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);
        currentLongitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.0);
    }
    else if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")){
        name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        phone = data.getStringExtra("phone");
        profile_pic_url = data.getStringExtra("profile_url");
        token = data.getStringExtra("token");
        currentLatitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);
        currentLongitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.0);
    }

    db = new SQliteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    //load user data from sqlite
    if(email != null && email !=" ") {
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getuserdetails(email);
        db_name = user.get("name");
        db_email = user.get("email");
        db_phone = user.get("phone");
        db_profile_pic = user.get("profile_pic");
        db_profile_pic_bg = user.get("profile_pic_bg");
        birthday = user.get("birthday");
    }else if(phone != null && phone !=" "){
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getuserdetails(phone);
        db_name = user.get("name");
        db_email = user.get("email");
        db_phone = user.get("phone");
        db_profile_pic = user.get("profile_pic");
        db_profile_pic_bg = user.get("profile_pic_bg");
        birthday = user.get("birthday");
    }


    edit_profile.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

    load_user_info();
}

public void load_user_info(){
    if(name != null && name !=""){
        tv_name.setText(name);
    }else if(db_name != null && db_name !=""){
        tv_name.setText(db_name);
    }

    if (email != " " && email != null){
        tv_email.setText(email);
    }else if(db_email != null && db_email != "") {
        tv_email.setText(db_email);
    }else {
        tv_email.setText(" ");
    }

    if(phone !=" " && phone !=null) {
        tv_phone.setText("+91 " + phone);
    }else if(db_phone !=null && db_phone !=" ") {
        tv_phone.setText(db_phone);
    }else {
        tv_phone.setText("");
    }
    if(profile_pic_url!=null && profile_pic_url != "") {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(profile_pic_url)
                .error(R.drawable.default_avtar)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
                .into(profile_pic);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.beach)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(heder_bg);
    }
    else if((db_profile_pic !=null && !db_profile_pic.equals(" "))&&(db_profile_pic_bg !=null && !db_profile_pic_bg.equals(" "))){
        byte[] db_profile;
        byte[] db_profile_bg;

        Bitmap db_profile_bitmap,db_profile_pic_bg_bitmap;
        db_profile = Base64.decode(db_profile_pic,Base64.DEFAULT);
        db_profile_bitmap = getBitmap(db_profile);

        db_profile_bg = Base64.decode(db_profile_pic_bg,Base64.DEFAULT);
        db_profile_pic_bg_bitmap = getBitmap(db_profile_bg);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(db_profile_bitmap)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
                .into(profile_pic);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(db_profile_pic_bg_bitmap)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(heder_bg);
    }else {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.default_avtar)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
                .into(profile_pic);
        Log.d("Default image set",TAG);
    }
    if(birthday !=" " && birthday !=null && birthday.equals("test")){
        tv_birthday.setText("Born on " + birthday);
    } else {
        tv_birthday.setText(" ");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    load_user_info();
    Log.d("in resume methode",TAG);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] bitmap) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmap , 0, bitmap.length);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.btn_edit_profile:
            Intent edit_profile = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditProfileActivity.class);
            edit_profile.putExtra("name",name);
            if((email !=null && email !="") && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                edit_profile.putExtra("email", email);
            }else if(phone != null && phone !="") {
                edit_profile.putExtra("phone", phone);
            }
            edit_profile.putExtra("profile_url",profile_pic_url);
            edit_profile.putExtra("token",token);
            edit_profile.putExtra("latitude",currentLatitude);
            edit_profile.putExtra("longitude",currentLongitude);
            startActivity(edit_profile);
            break;

        case R.id.iv_profile_back:
            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(home);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")) { ...} else if(data.hasExtra("name") && data.hasExtra("email") && data.hasExtra("profile_url") && data.hasExtra("token")){  ...` They are the same! It's like `if (true) {...} else if (true) { ... }` What is this? You probably wanted to check the `phone` string, right?

Comment: yes if there is email or phone is coming from activity..

Comment: ok! but your `if` and `else if` statement contain exactly the same condition. Hope you understand what I am telling you. It would be like writing `if (val == 5) { ... } else if (val == 5) { ... }`. Did my answer help you though? If you do not understand those concepts, I suggest you post your code on the Code Review Site.

Comment: i make changes in that it checking email in both condition thanks for pointing it.

Comment: remember to post some updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Before OP posted code**

You can define a function that loads your data for `ProfileActivity` and call it in [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onresume).

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (this.reloadNedeed)
        this.reloadProfileData();

    this.reloadNeeded = false; // do not reload anymore, unless I tell you so...
}
```

This way, since `onResume()` is also called after `onCreate()`, 
you'd be using the same code both for when the the activity is first created and for when you re-open it (e.g. when you come back from another activity, or another app).

In order to make it work, `reloadNedeed` must be set to true by default:

```
private boolean reloadNeed = true;
```

---

In order to start the `EditActivity` you can do:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(EditActivity.class), EDIT_CODE);
```

where `EDIT_CODE` can be any number, e.g:

```
private static final int EDIT_CODE = 31;
```

When you want to get back to from `EditActivity` you just call:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent); // or RESULT_CANCELED if user did not make any changes
// it would be better to use some custom defined codes here
finish();
```

This would trigger the function [onActivityResult(int, int Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) in `ProfileActivity`, in which you can tell the activity to reload the data.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == EDIT_CODE) { // Ah! We are back from EditActivity, did we make any changes?
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Yes we did! Let's allow onResume() to reload the data
            this.reloadNeeded = true;
        }    
    }
```

`onResume()` is called **after** `onActivityResult()`, so we can safely decide whether to put `reloadNeeded` to true, or just leave it to false.

---

**Edit: After OP posted code**

I haven't tested your code, but I may have found some oddities just by looking at it.

I believe you may have a problem with some `if-else conditions` in your `load_user_info()` function.

When you get back from `EditActivity` the activity is (most likely) not created again. Only `onResume()` is called, which calls `load_user_info()`;

But since the Activity **isn't** recreated, your variables hold the same values from when they were initialized in `onCreate()`.

When he does check the data:

```
if(name != null && name !=""){
    tv_name.setText(name);
}else if(db_name != null && db_name !=""){
    tv_name.setText(db_name);
}
```

your activity says:

*Heyy, name is not null and is different than ""* (by the way you should use `equals()`, even for literals)

*Therefore, I will execute this piece of code* `tv_name.setText(name);`, *and since it's an `if else` statement, the second block will NOT be executed*.

So your activity, never really displays the updated data. The same data as before is displayed.

You should try to apply the same logic as I posted in my original answer.

Hope I understood your question right...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you are asking. There's the simple(ish) way and the hard(er) and more correct way.

The easiest way is to refresh the data you're expecting in the `onResume` of the activity you are returning to. If you navigate to a different activity, the previous activity will call `onPause`, then `onResume` when you return, and at that time you can check for new data and load it in place. That's the quicker way.

A better, more correct way of doing it would be to implement a `ViewModel` and use `LiveData` to allow the Activity to always have the most up to date data. This does require a bit of extra effort on your end to make sure your app has proper architecture, but in the long run pays off way better. Check out Android's [architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html).

Comment: when i click on save button then it saves the data in sqlite and returning to profile activity and in onResume method of profile activity i called the load user method which takes updated data from sqlite but its not getting set in textview and when i press back button its showing me the updated data

Comment: To troubleshoot exactly what's going on there, more info would be needed. Can't tell exactly why the data isn't loading without knowing the Activity's code.

Comment: You're loading in the new information via Intent data, which is fine, but you're only setting it through `onCreate`, which will not always be called. You can add an override of `onNewIntent` to help handle that, but the information I gave is still accurate - you're not loading the data from the `onResume` part of the lifecycle. Android lifecycles can be very fickle.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your activity data:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 0):

onBackPressed or finish() then its call and refresh

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

I hope this helpful...